# Sign Android App contains Google Maps

Tags: android, adt, google-maps-api-2, android-keystore

I created one small app in which I used `Google Maps API v2`.

For testing and debugging, I used the default debug keystore that is generated named as debug.keystore.

I generated my SHA key that has to be provided for using maps and generated api key and used in my application. I signed the application using EXPORT wizard in eclipse and am creating my new key store for my app and generating application apk.

But now when I am trying to run this app on device the MAP is not displayed.

As I suspect this is due to new keystore for my app and i have registered my debug keystore SHA key to google console.

What am i doing wrong here and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While signing an application with different `keystore` from debug one, you should create another `API_KEY` using `SHA1` generated from your current `keystore` and register it in `Google API Console` and use that key for `Google Maps`. Your maps won't show up,because `API_KEY` is generated by the current keystore and your package name. Changing keystore file will cause your `MapView` to shows blank, because `SHA1` is different.

So as a final answer, you should repeat all steps to generate an `API_KEY` for `Google Maps` with new `SHA1`.

**Edit**: There are two options which you can use to create `SHA1` from `keystore` file.

1. `keytool -list -v -keystore <path_to_your_keystore>` will give you `SHA1`.
2. Using `Eclipse` if you try to sign your app with your keystore, at the end before saving your `.apk` file it will shows you `SHA1` and `MD5` generated from your keystore. I think it was the second time when you try to sign apk.

Comment: can you tell me how can i do it?I am having some mis-concepts in generating SHA1 because i need to specify keystore in command am i right?

Comment: i tried the second step but it is not done it does not show me any SHA1 and MD5 please tell me how can i do it?

Comment: It won't show the first time, I think it was showing the second time after you sign your apk. If it's not working try the first step.

Comment: hey bro still i am unable to do it.i don't know how to sign this app that contain maps i followed your 1st step i found some keys using keytool command from my App Certificate like SHA1, SHA256 and many others then i generated new API key from that SHA1 and used that particular key in my app but it still shows blank.Help me out bro.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43444/discussion-between-nirav-kamani-and-android-developer)